# If the universe is expanding then why does the distance between Sun and the Earth is not expanding?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion

It has been proved that universe is expanding in the accelerating way. If that is true than the space between the Sun and the Earth must also be expanding. But it is not so, why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does space expansion not expand matter?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2110/)

Comment: There are lots of duplicate questions I could have chosen. basically the attractive force of gravity within the Solar System is many orders of magnitude stronger than the force due to the expansion of space. Try [this search](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=expansion+solar+system) to see related questions.

Comment: In other words, the space between the Sun and the Earth is of course expanding as well - it's just that gravity forces the distance between the two to get back to where it was, mostly.